# Liveware.emit not working in global javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a laravel emit in a liveware blade file as follows:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            Livewire.emit('nextSlot');
        }, 4000);
    });
</script>
```

This does not work, it does not emit the nextSlot function in the respected php file.

Note, this hwoever does work as expected:

```
<button wire:click="nextSlot">
    Next Slot
</button>
```

Any reason why my emit inside the `<script>` tags don't work?
And what can I do to emit an event after a setTimeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an event listenter on your Component for your client event:

```
protected $listeners ['nextSlot'];
```

The above will listen for a `nextSlot` event being raised and call a method in you Component called `nextSlot`. If your event name and method do not match, you would need to specify the name of the method to be called.

```
protected $listeners = ['nextSlot' => 'methodName'];
```

Also note that your `nextSlot` event will be fired just once after 4 seconds. Not sure if that is what you want or if you want the event fired every 4 seconds. If you want the latter, replace `setTimeout()` with `setInterval()`.

```js
document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
    setInterval(() => Livewire.emit('nextSlot'), 4000);
})
```

Comment: This worked for me, also, the liveware:load works for me, so I just updated the nextSlot listener thing, and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: @AsaadMahmood You're right about `livewire:load`. That was my issue with accidentally capitalizing the `L`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.Livewire.emit('func', 'data');`

Answer (score 0):

If your `wire:click` works but the `Livewire.emit` isn't working this might be caused by the different type. The click is a specific event that calls the related method directly while emit only calls the method, if the `listeners` array contains it. Have you added it to the listener? If you share you component code, it should be easier to debug.

Comment: Added it in the original post. I don't think I have added into the listeners array. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Livewire 3 you can use the code below:

`Livewire.dispatch()`

Link: [Livewire Events](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/events#dispatching-events)